# nothing showing in captcha code of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha, recaptcha

i m doing something wrong with gd2 library of image 
this is my index controller

```
public function index()
    {   
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
         $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $vals = array(
                'img_path'   => './captcha/',
                'img_url'    => base_url().'public/img/captcha/',
                'img_width'  => '200',
                'img_height' => 30,
                'border' => 0, 
                'expiration' => 7200,
                );

                 // create captcha image
                $cap = create_captcha($vals);
                print_r($cap);
                // store image html code in a variable
                $arrData['image'] = $cap['image'];

               // store the captcha word in a session
                $this->session->set_userdata('word', $cap['word']);
        $arrData['middle'] = 'contact';
        $this->load->view('template',$arrData);
    }
```

this above code is my index function of controller

this is my view

```
<div class="enquiry-deatils">
          <label>Type character * :</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="" class="captcha"/>
          <label><img src="images/capcha.jpg" /></label>
          <?php echo $image;  // this will show the captcha image ?>
        </div>
```

i dont know whats the error its showing me nothing

Comment: did you inspect the image element in firebug?

Comment: yes its show me blank no image tag

Comment: then do print_r($arrData); in controller before passing to view.

Comment: this is show me this output  Array ( [image] => [middle] => contact )

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504514/how-to-use-captcha-plugin-in-codeigniter?rq=1

Comment: not working and that guy code also not working for that

Comment: Is captcha image getting generated in your captcha folder?

Comment: no folder is empty i think problem with gd2 image library

Answer (score 0):

Try this-
provide complete path to img_path and img_url. like this-

```
  $vals = array(
            'img_path'   => 'mysite/public/img/captcha/',
            'img_url'    => 'mysite/public/img/captcha/',
            'img_width'  => '150',
            'img_height' => 30,
            'expiration' => 7200,
            "time" => time()
            );
```

Comment: sorry not working still getting blank.nothing in $arrData['image]

Comment: but, is the image getting generated in captcha folder this time? see

Comment: Nope still empty folder

Comment: Then i would suggest, use different captcha library. There's surely some configuration problem with your captcha library